# Temporarily use something else as home directory

Tags: home

If it is possible, should be pretty basic, but I am puzzled how to ask Google the right question (or it is impossible).

Lets say we have

```
/home/user/
...conf
/home/user/candidate/
...conf
```

We have homedir and some subdir.. programs will use naturally from homedir(`*/home/user*`)

What I need is to temporarily change home user to `*/home/user/candidate*`, so programs will call `*/home/user/candidate/conf*`, instead `*/home/user/conf*`

Now, I don't need usermod or anything else to change permanently `/etc/passwd`, i want to temporarily force programs to use my directory, thinking it is home, but on reboot fetch `*/home/user*` and act normal.

Using `*/home/user/candidate*` as home only session long, no usermod stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use bind mount to make this redirection:

```
mount --bind /home/user/candidate/ /home/user/
```

This way, `/home/user` will show the contents of it´s subdir `candidate`. After making all you need, umount will destroy the binding:

```
umount /home/user/
```

More docs about bind mount:

- [How to use bind mounts in linux](http://backdrift.org/how-to-use-bind-mounts-in-linux)
- [3.13. Bind Mounts and File System Mount Order](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Global_File_System_2/s1-manage-mountorder.html)

Comment: that would do perfectly if it to do as i think it will.
off to another station, will let know of result

Comment: i´ve made a test inside /tmp and it worked as expected. hope it works for you too. Cheers

Comment: seems perfect. as i was thinking, it isnt hard, after you know what to look for.. google answers gave usermod answers, and i can assume i asked wrong questions

Comment: Another option is `aufs`, that is something like a overlay filesystem to multiple directories into one mountpoint. Could be usefull to make `/home/user` read-only and `/home/user/foo` read-write. I just don´t if it will work as mount bind with subdirs. - http://aufs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't want to just `export HOME=/home/user/candidate`?

Answer (score 4):

A more portable, fleeting solution that doesn't involve mounting one folder over another (yuck) is to just `export HOME=/home/user/candidate`.

Comment: If you run `HOME=/home/user/candidate "$SHELL"` you get a shell with a displaced `HOME`. Type `exit` to exit that shell.